# The six letters that could?

Tags: word

I’ve been working with word searches a lot lately and it gave me an idea for a short but hopefully fun little puzzle. Let’s take a word like *scones*, and let’s break it down into as many words as possible:

```
scones
scone
cones
cone
ones
con
one
on
```

Well that was fun, it turns out that *scones* is a surely an overachiever. It gave me 8 words without having to rearrange any of the letters. Note that *cons* doesn’t make the list because you have to remove the letter *e*.

---

Which six-letter word can produce the most words, without rearranging or removing letters?

<sub>For the purposes of this puzzle, a word is considered valid if it exists in [YAWL](https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl). If you prefer a more organized list of words, my [brute force dictionary](https://github.com/tacosontitan/brute-force-dictionary/tree/master/BruteForceDictionary/Text%20Files) (which is just an organized version of YAWL that will never change), is also available.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how we can *check* that a given candidate produces as many words as possible, given the [no-computers] tag. But, depending on whether you are counting the number of *different words* or the number of *substrings that are words*,

> ananas

is hard to beat. The only substrings that aren't YAWL words are

> the three "n"s.

Oh, except that

> in fact YAWL doesn't have one-letter words, so in this word *every* substring that's long enough to be in YAWL is in YAWL. This is therefore definitely optimal for the substrings-that-are-words question.

But there are a lot of repeated words there and only

> 9/10 distinct words: (a,) an, ana, anan, anana, ananas, na, nan, nana, nanas.

For *distinct words*, I have no reason to think this is optimal (other than having tried for a while and not found anything better) but

> latest

yields

> 13: la lat late latest; at ate ates; te tes test; es est; st.

EDITED to add: Now that the [no-computers] tag has been removed, I can report that a very simple-minded Python program finds

> ferest

yielding

> 14: fe fer fere feres ferest; er ere  eres; re res rest; es est; st.

I did know

> the word "fere" but (1) didn't think of it -- it's pretty obscure -- and (2) didn't know it could be an adjective and (3) likely wouldn't have thought of it anyway because I have no idea why YAWL considers "fe" a word. So hooray for computer searches!

But

> actually there are several other 14s, some of which I really should have thought of. STATES, AMUSED, BAREST, CHIDES, SPARED, STARES, PHONED, for instance. 24 in all.

Simple-minded Python code, in case anyone cares:

```
words = set(w.strip() for w in open("yawl.txt","r").read().split())
m = (0,'',set())
for w in words:
    if len(w) != 6: continue
    s = set()
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(i+1,7):
            if w[i:j] in words: s.add(w[i:j])
    n = len(s)
    if n > m[0]: m = (n,w,s)
print(m)
```

Comment: I removed the [tag:no-computers] tag for that specific reason. There is a rather small handful of words that fit the criteria, and your second answer is *very* close to the maximum.